# How to add lims with custom break in scatterplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a beginner in R. I would like to customize x and y-axis to make it break in every 10^2 (starting from 10, continuing with 100, 1k, 10k, 100k and ending with 1M).

Here is my code:

```
axs <- ggplot(fatality, aes(x= confirmed, y= deaths, label=country))+ geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(deaths>24543,as.character(country),'')),hjust=-0.1,vjust=0)
    > axs
    > axs + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(10,1000,10000,100000,1000000)
```

[image: Here is my plot]
Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd supply a minimal, reproducable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could use the `scales` package to use the `label_number()` function.

```
axs <- ggplot(fatality, aes(x= confirmed, y= deaths, label=country))+ geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(deaths>24543,as.character(country),'')),hjust=-0.1,vjust=0)
    > axs
    > axs + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(10,1000,10000,100000,1000000), labels = scales::label_number())
```

If you want the display with the k and M suffix you could change the label_number part to `label_number_si`.

Comment: thank you but it still gives a "+" as an output to continue

Comment: Sorry, I missed a parentheses, I just fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with package `scales` but in logarithmic scale and formatted the axis labels.

First load the necessary packages, aggregate the data and start the plot with its basic elements.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggrepel)

df %>%
  group_by(countryName) %>%
  summarise(deaths = sum(death),
            confirmed = sum(confirmed)) %>%
  filter(deaths > 0, confirmed > 0) %>%
  mutate(country = ifelse(deaths > 24543, countryName, "")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(confirmed, deaths)) +
  geom_point() -> axs
```

Now 2 plots.

One with `geom_text`.

```
axs + geom_text(aes(label = country, hjust = -0.1, vjust = 0)) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

[image]

Another with `geom_text_repel` to have the text labels move away from one another.

```
axs + geom_text_repel(aes(label = country, hjust = -0.1, vjust = 0),
                      direction = "x") +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

[image]

## Data

The data is taken from the code in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61577238/8245406).

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')
df$day <- as.Date(df$day, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! But,  "R: Error in UseMethod(“group_by_”) : applied to an object of class" I'm getting this error while applying the first step of the code :(

Comment: @Ipek Can you run `str(df)` and see what is the class of the column producing the error?

Comment: Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame:  $ country = chr /// $ confirmed = num /// $ deaths = num /// $ case_fatality = chr

Comment: @Ipek I have just rerun the code, downloading the data again like in the post, and cannot reproduce the error. What is `class(df$countryName)`?

Comment: It looks perfect.. Thank you